# UIColectionViewCell didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have two classes UICollectionViewCell. I display both classes in cellForItemAtIndexPath . How to determine this class in didSelectItemAtIndexPath? I need when i select one class it performs some action, and when i select another class it performs other actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will know by just checking its class type using.For example you have two classes inherits from UICollectionViewCell named **cellclass1** and **cellclass2**.Then in **didSelectAtIndexpath**

```
if ([cell isMemberOfClass:[cellclass1 class]]){
    //Do cellclass1 stuff
}
else{
     // Do cellclass2 stuff

}
```